# How to use custom dispForm in sharepoint list view?

Tags: sharepoint

I am using list view to show the list items in share point 2013. When user clicks the title the custom page should be shown instead of default display page(dispForm.aspx) of share-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define XmlDocuments in contentType:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543825.aspx

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Workflow Task (0x010801) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010100AF4E4BE6CF8048959C4172F4298CE42A"
               Name="MyName"
               Group="MyGroup"
               Description="MyDescription"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
        <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
          <New>_layouts/MyFolder/New.aspx</New>
          <Display>_layouts/MyFolder/New.aspx</Display>
          <Edit>_layouts/MyFolder/Edit.aspx</Edit>
        </FormUrls>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

In code behind you get current item

```
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
```